# Passing parameters from view to controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, url

I have this basic question

Is this :

```
<a href="userconsole/indivstore/<?php echo $obj->store_id; ?>/">
<?php echo $obj->title; ?></a>
```

Different from this:

```
<a href="/userconsole/indivstore/<?php echo $obj->store_id; ?>/">
<?php echo $obj->title; ?></a>
```

Or is there no difference?

(I am using CodeIgniter at present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="userconsole/indivstore/<?php echo $obj->store_id; ?>/">` is relative URL
so if you are on `http://host/site/current-page` it will point to `http://host/site/current-page/userconsole/indivstore/<?php echo $obj->store_id; ?>` which is wrong

`<a href="/userconsole/indivstore/<?php echo $obj->store_id; ?>/">` is absolute URL so if you are on `http://host/site/current-page` it will point to `http://host/userconsole/indivstore/<?php echo $obj->store_id; ?>` which is wrong if your site is under a sub folder.

the correct way to generate URL with codeigniter is using site_url() helper
please check http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've missed something, the only difference (and there is at least one difference) is in the HTML, not in the PHP per se.

The second one has a link that starts with a `/`, so that means it points to the link at

```
http://yoursite.tld/userconsole/etc
```

the first one points to `/userconsole/etc` relative from the place you call it. So if you are in the dir `/yourpath`, it will point you to `http://yoursite.tld/yourpath/userconsole/etc`

Answer (score 1):

Lets say ur on www.somesite.com/url/

With

```
<a href="userconsole/indivstore/<?php echo $obj->store_id; ?>/">
<?php echo $obj->title; ?></a>
```

Ur Going to `www.somesite.com/url/userconsole/indivstore/`

With

```
<a href="/userconsole/indivstore/<?php echo $obj->store_id; ?>/">
<?php echo $obj->title; ?></a>
```

Here is the `/` important! your going back to your root path that means `www.somesite.com`.
The result: `www.somesite.com/userconsole/indivstore/`

So at all its realative vs absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

The first link has a relative path to the actual page you are visiting, but the second page has the absolute path so:

If you are at: `http://example.com/something/other-thing`

In first case the next url will be: `http://example.com/something/other-thing/userconsole..etc`
In the second case the next url will be: `http://example.com/userconsole..etc`